# Using more than 2 attributes gives an error

Tags: shader, webgl

I have an issue with WebGL shaders.

I have multiple shader programs.

When all of my shaders have 2 attributes (types don't matter), the polygons are drawn fine.

However, if I add one more attribute to any program, none of the polygons are drawn, and "attribs not set up correctly" error is given when `DrawArrays` is called.

All vertex attribute arrays are enabled, and an array buffer is bound to all attributes. I can't find the cause of the error, everything is done the same way as before, just with different attribute index.

I tried both `Get` and `BindAttribLocation`, and I get the same result.

How do I use more than 2 attributes in my programs?

Comment: *"I can't find the cause of the error"* - Me neither, all of your posted code is 100% correct, since **no code at all** cannot contain **any errors**. And likewise I doubt that `glDrawArrays` actually gives an error of *"attribs not set up correctly"*, since no OpenGL error could have such a description. So there might be an additional layer between you and OpenGL (and you're not calling `glDrawArrays` directly) which might choke on more than two attributes, even if GL doesn't. And last but not least, do the shaders compile and link correctly? If not, what do the info logs say?

Comment: `since no OpenGL error could have such a description` It's WebGL. The shaders compiled and linked well. I'm calling DrawArrays to draw all polygons, except for the sky ones.

Comment: Ah Ok, then you may want to retag your question (well, I'll probably do it myself). And still, post some code (drawing, shader creation/setup).

Comment: I don't know what I did, but now I see everything when the world is drawn, but when it's not, I don't see the GUI.

Comment: The error is not gone, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moved `Enable/DisableVertexAttribArray` from initialization code to drawing code. Now it's working!